# oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout causing connection leaks in Oracle connection pool JDBC7

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am currently trying to add a timeout for the database operations at JVM level. I tried adding a **oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout** and tested it out with a slow query. It was working fine and the operation did throw a **java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out** as expected when the operation reached the timeout. But then I found that after the connection is timed out, such connections are not checked back in to the connection pool. They were counted as checked out connections and kept in a checked out connections list (**OracleImplicitConnectionCache.checkedOutConnectionList**). Continuous growth of such unusable connections in the pool will eventually fill up the pool until no more connections will be given out as maximum limit of the connection pool is reached.

There is actually no point even if these connections are checked back in to the pool because they are already closed and marked as isUsable = false in the **oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection** class. So ideally, these connections should get completely removed from the pool. Hence appreciate if anyone could provide me some clarifications on following.

1. If we use **oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout**, is there a way of evicting the unusable connections which gathers in the connection pool after being read timed out?
2. Is there any other way of specifying a read time out at JVM level for Database operations?
   Please note that **java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout(int timeout)** is also not an option because then we have to set it for each and every query

I am really grateful if someone could provide me some assistance on the above.

Following is a sample code on the above scenario,

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty( "oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout", "2000" );

        checkTimeOut();
        Thread.sleep( 4000 );

        String answer = getUserInput();
        while( answer.toUpperCase().startsWith( "Y" ) )
        {
            checkTimeOut();
            Thread.sleep( 4000 );
            answer = getUserInput();
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getUserInput()
{
    String answer = "";
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        System.out.println( "Continue?" );
        answer = br.readLine();
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return answer;
}

private static void checkTimeOut()
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Date time = null;
    try
    {
        time = new Date();

        String sql = "";//slow query here
        con = PoolFactory.getConnectionPool( "ORACLE" ).getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit( false );
        ps = con.prepareStatement( sql );

        ps.executeUpdate();
        commit( con );
        System.out.println( "Successfully Updated" );
        System.out.println( new Date().getTime() - time.getTime() );
    }
    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "Failed to Update" );
        System.out.println( new Date().getTime() - time.getTime() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        rollback( con );
    }
    finally
    {
        close( ps );
        close( con );
    }
}

private static void close( PreparedStatement ps )
{
    if( ps != null )
    {
        try
        {
            ps.close();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void commit( Connection con )
{
    if( con != null )
    {
        try
        {
            con.commit();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void rollback( Connection con )
{
    if( con != null )
    {
        try
        {
            con.rollback();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void close( Connection con )
{
    if( con != null )
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Found More Information

When I set **AbandonedConnectionTimeout = 2** the background thread **OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread** will try to recover the connections abandoned for more than **2 seconds**. But this thread fails recovering these timed out connections because of the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2254)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.getAutoCommit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:138)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.closeCheckedOutConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1395)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.runAbandonedTimeout(OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.run(OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.java:80)
```

The recovery process get aborted after this exception

Comment: Code please. At a guess you aren't closing the connection when you get a read timeout, but we should not have to guess.

Comment: And why you think they need to be removed? Just because `isUsable` is ` false` does not mean it won't be resurrected and used again.

Comment: @tsolakp - These timed out connections are counted as connections in use in the pool. So eventually such connections will fill up the maximum limit of the pool and will not give out any new connections. Pool will have to be re initialized

Comment: @EJP - I will add the code and I actually do close the connection but as I have mentioned it is not getting removed from the **OracleImplicitConnectionCache.checkedOutConnectionList**

Comment: @tsolakp - if these connections are getting **resurrected** it is fine. But I waited for few minutes but they remained in the **OracleImplicitConnectionCache.checkedOutConnectionList**.

Comment: Hi @VirtuousWarman, did you find an answer to your question? If yes, care to share? Thanks.